# curl: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Tags: terminal

I am trying to download a file from ftp server, but I keep getting an error message about illegal url format.

The command I am using is this:

```
curl -o '/Downloads/ISP_Orders_last.csv' 'ftp://"Name Surname":mypassword@"x.xx.xxx.x/Marketing/Reports/60 ISP Report/ISP_Orders_last.csv"'
```

I guess that the issue is with spaces in the url, I tried to put the whole url in "" but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about Apple products or services as defined in the [Help] and would probably be a better fit in [SO]

Comment: @allan `curl` questions are on-topic, as are questions about other Terminal commands.

Comment: Can you please rerun the command with the `--verbose` option and then copy/paste the command you run and the error message you got in full, too often details get lost when paraphasing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anywhere there are spaces in the URL, try replacing them with a `%20`.  So in your case it would be `60%20ISP%20Report`.

So this...

```
ftp://Name Surname:mypassword@x.xx.xxx.x/Marketing/Reports/60 ISP Report/ISP_Orders_last.csv
```

Would be...

```
ftp://Name%20Surname:mypassword@x.xx.xxx.x/Marketing/Reports/60%20ISP%20Report/ISP_Orders_last.csv
```

Comment: Hi, it totally worked! Thank you.

Comment: @TomášJelínek Glad  I can help. The proper way to thank someone is to upvote their answer and if the answer solved your problem, mark it as the accepted answer.